# Changing colors in JS with conditionals

Tags: javascript, colors, addition

I am doing mini JS counter projects. Everything is great, although I am stuck with giving "0" a particular colour.
So far, my code looks as follow

```js
(function() {
  const counter = document.querySelector('h1');
  const add = document.querySelector('.increase');
  const substract = document.querySelector('.decrease');
  let count = 0;

  add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter.innerHTML = count++;
    if (count > 0) {
      counter.classList.add('over')
    }
  })

  substract.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter.innerHTML = count--;
    if (count < 0) {
      counter.classList.add('under')
    }
  })
})()
```

```css
.over {
  color: green;
}

.under {
  color: red;
}

.zero {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="counter.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>0</h1>
  <button class="decrease">-</button>
  <button class="increase">+</button>
  <script src="counter.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What happens is that I cannot add class 'zero' in both conditionals by any means. Whether I try to add class 'zero' to each button by else if or else counter's colour remains green or red regardless of its value.

Comment: Beside adding a specific class to the `<h1>` element, you'll have to remove the other classes (eg: `counter.classList.remove('over', 'under', 'zero')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it fix:

```
(function () {
            const counter = document.querySelector('h1');
            const add = document.querySelector('.increase');
            const substract = document.querySelector('.decrease');
            let count = 0;

            add.addEventListener('click', function () {
                count++;
                counter.innerHTML = count
                if (count > 0) {
                    counter.classList.add('over');
                    counter.classList.remove('under')
                } else if(count === 0) {
                    counter.classList.remove('under')
                    counter.classList.remove('over')
                }
            })


            substract.addEventListener('click', function () {
                count--;
                counter.innerHTML = count
                if (count < 0) {
                    counter.classList.add('under')
                    counter.classList.remove('over')
                } else if(count === 0) {
                    counter.classList.remove('under')
                    counter.classList.remove('over')
                }
            })
        })()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to un-assign the other css classes in order for the proper one to be displayed at  all times.

```js
(function() {
  const counter = document.querySelector('h1');
  const add = document.querySelector('.increase');
  const substract = document.querySelector('.decrease');
  let count = 0;

  add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter.innerHTML = ++count;
    if (count > 0) {
     counter.classList.remove('under', 'zero')
      counter.classList.add('over')
    }
    else if (count == 0) {
     counter.classList.remove('under', 'over')
      counter.classList.add('zero')
    }
  })

  substract.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter.innerHTML = --count;
    if (count < 0) {
     counter.classList.remove('over', 'zero')
      counter.classList.add('under')
    }
    else if (count == 0) {
     counter.classList.remove('under', 'over')
      counter.classList.add('zero')
    }
  })
})()
```

```css
.over {
  color: green;
}

.under {
  color: red;
}

.zero {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="counter.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>0</h1>
  <button class="decrease">-</button>
  <button class="increase">+</button>
  <script src="counter.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As a side note, I noticed that the value was also not showing the correct number when clicking the plus and minus buttons. In the code I changed 'count++' and 'count--' to '++count' and '--count'. This changes the order of operations. For example 'count++' assigns the count to the html AND THEN increments the variable, but '++count' increments the variable AND THEN assigns the new value to the html.